# "A questo punto" o "in questo punto": qual è la preposizione giusta in questo contesto?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Ho avuto il dubbio su quale preposizione,  "a" oppure "in", si debba usare in questa frase:

> Luigi abita ___ questo punto del distretto dell'Eixample di Barcellona.

Ho il sospetto che la preposizione corretta sia "in": ho trovato l'espressione "a questo punto" in alcuni dizionari, ma ha tutt'altro significato. Tuttavia, non ho saputo trovare conferma dalle ricerche che ho fatto sui dizionari. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è la preposizione giusta nella frase precedente?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La tua intuizione è corretta, devi usare la preposizione ***in*** nella frase

> Luigi abita **in** questo punto del distretto dell'Eixample di Barcellona.

Infatti ***a questo punto*** indica un instante temporale o anche lo stato di una situazione, come riportato dal [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/a-questo-punto):

> 1. in questo momento, ora: a questo punto entra in scena Arlecchino
> 2. stando così le cose: a questo punto, tanto vale aspettare

L'espressione ***in questo punto*** indica invece una posizione fisica più precisa di un oggetto o di un luogo.

Ad esempio:

> Il negozio si trova in questo punto della via

(immagina di indicare al tuo interlocutore il punto su una mappa)

> Ho un dolore in questo punto della gamba

(indicando con un dito la zona dolorante)

Comment: However, *Luigi abita **a** Barcellona*

Comment: @abarisone, grazie per la modifica, ma non capisco ancora in che modo non da madrelingua dovrei scegliere una espressione al posto dell´altra.

Comment: ad esempio:  "Ma se il cammino del giovane Stato unitario era stato così lento da meritare di essere giudicato «stentato», se il giovane organismo recava in sé il segno di malattie che gli stavano dentro e ne minavano lo slancio al punto che anche quel che si era ottenuto lo era stato, non per l’impeto di una forza creatrice di storia, ma «girando ostacoli o profittando delle vie che […] si aprivano innanzi» (p. 139),

Comment: sembra difficile non ammettere che **in questo punto** fosse proprio l’antichità della storia italiana a far valere i suoi diritti con il peso che faceva gravare sulle iniziative e con il suggerimento che forniva dell’astuzia in luogo della generosità, dello spirito di compromesso in luogo del coraggio e della forza."

Comment: puoi copiare il testo messo tra i due commenti a virgolette e cercare per avere la fonte dalla treccani, e da madrelingua o una o l´altra espressione suonano giuste a mio parere (oltre a non sapere come "indicare con o senza dito" questa o quella zona nella frase da me riportata)

Comment: @mle, che cosa non ti è chiaro? Come ha ben spiegato abarisone, “in questo punto” indica una posizione fisica, “a questo punto” indica un momento o uno stato di cose. Poi è chiaro che la lingua è flessibile, e se uno vuole usare metaforicamente “in questo punto” per riferirlo a una fase storica – come nel tuo esempio – va benissimo.

Comment: @DaG, l´ultima tua frase del tuo commento risponde alla mia questione.. si possono usare, e suonano leciti, modi come "giunti a/in questo punto del discorso conviene forse aprire una parentesi".. commentavo per aggiungere una flessibilitá alle due espressioni per maggiore completezza aldilá della spiegazione in senso stretto/proprio che da abarisone. È ovvio, se ci limitiamo alla questione di Charo poteva abarisone lasciare la prima frase del suo commento e tralasciare tutto il resto...